# Pass MD5 value to prepopulate field

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, encryption

this is my scenario:

I have a gravity form A where i collect user data and users are automatically registered to my site (via gravity forms user registration plugin). Users then automatically login and go to gravity form B where i collect some more data.

I have a field in form B that is prepopulated via code in functions.php and is supposed to store the MD5 hash of user_login and user_email (remember that user is automatically logged in).

This is the code

```
    add_filter("gform_field_value_editlink", "get_editlink");
function get_editlink(){
    $editlink = md5($user_login . $user_email);
       return $editlink;
}
```

The problem is that instead it passes (i suppose) a different MD5 hash, probably of the words "$user_login" and "$user_email" as if the user was not logged in (but it is!!!)

What do you think is the problem?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I know i'm partially OT but the core of the problem is MD5 related, I could have had the same issue with no plugin at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution (I've been working on this for 2 days)

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_editlink", "get_editlink");
function get_editlink(){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_login = $current_user->user_login;
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    $editlink = md5($user_login . $user_email);
       return $editlink;
}
```